# checkout as a guest and delayed account creation

Tags: e-commerce

if a customer decided to create an account after a guest check out (Delayed account creation), would the order that they ordered at that time be saved in their account?

Comment: As a user, yes please. Sometimes I do guest checkout because I don't think I'll need to come back, and then of course I'm wrong and I need to make an account to see a Your Orders page in the hope that it'll link up...

Answer (score 1):

It's a common practice in e-commerce and booking flights, and it's technically feasible using email or phone number mapping. For example, during the checkout process for buying shoes, customers could be asked for their email or phone number for the purpose of receiving an e-receipt. If they later use the same email or phone number to create an account, all their previous orders should be visible.

To make the process of linking guest orders to customer accounts seamless, it's important to provide a clear message during the checkout process about the benefits of creating an account. Additionally, creating a password could be made part of the checkout process to make creating an account completely frictionless.